# Why do clients always want user account creation to be via AD and security using AD security groups?

Tags: active-directory

So this isn't a 'how to'. From a bang for buck POV, putting our application's security into AD doesn't seem even close to worth the effort. We have a lot of security/user related attributes and use roles for consistency.
Access levels are configured by application specialists, not sys admins.
So why do all the RFPs I look at demand AD for user account creation and AD security groups for security admin?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Who said you have to be a sysadmin to manage entities in Active Directory? AD as an integration requirement exists for the simple reason that AD is a popular choice of IAM platform.

Comment: A company would prefer to use a single IAM across all its applications, rather than try to manage a separate IAM created and (hopefully) maintained by individual applications.  This helps provide structure across all applications and provides benefits for auditing access to resources and onboarding new personnel.